# Determine if each coefficient of polynomial is congruent to $0$ modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, congruences

Let $p\in\mathbb{P}$. Consider the polynomial
$$f(t) = (t-1)(t-2)\ldots (t-(p-1)) -t^{p-1}+1 $$
Show that every coefficient is divisible by $p$.
The first thing to notice is that we have $p-1$ factors, therefore the summands $t^{p-1}$ cancel or in other words, the coefficient for $t^{p-1}$ is zero and is divisible by $p$.

Multiplying everything through seems veeery tedious. Can we get by easier, somehow?
We would have something like this:
$$f(t) = 0t^{p-1}+A_1t^{p-2} + A_2t^{p-3} +\ldots A_{p-2}t +(1+\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}i) $$
We could suppose for a contradiction that one of the coefficients is not congruent to $0$ modulo $p$, but this doesn't help, because, for one - there is no information on congruence of $f(t)$ and secondly, why would the constant term have to satisfy that congruence in general?

..or have I mis-understood the problem? How to proceed?

Comment: The constant term is $(p-1)!$ which you should know by ******'s theorem is what?

Comment: How do you arrive at $(p-1)!$ as the constant term? :< What happened to the $+1$ at the end? Not sure whose theorem you have in mind: it would look like there is congruence to $p-1$ or $-1$ modulo $p$ since $p-2$ is congruent to 1 modulo $p$.

Comment: You're right. I missed the $1$. I was talking about Wilson's theorem.

Comment: Ok, the constant term is 0, so now it remains to see if all the other coefficients also obey that congruence. That's the part that looks extremely tedious, to compute $A_i$.

Comment: $(p-2)!\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ is what I meant.

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking about it. Each of those $A_k$ seem to be sums of $\binom {p-1} k$ elements so I'm thinking a combinatorial identity is involved somewhere so we finally end up with elements like $\binom {p} k$ which we know are divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very cute problem. Let me make one innocuous observation before I begin:

A non-zero polynomial of degree $n$ defined over a field can have at most $n$ roots.

Now let us begin: Plug in various values for $t$ in $f(t)=(t-1)(t-2)\cdots (t-(p-1))-t^{p-1}+1$. We see that $f(0)=(p-1)!+1 \equiv0 \pmod p$ by Wilson's theorem. For any other value of $t$ modulo $p$, i.e. $1\leq t_0 \leq p-1$, we notice that the product $(t_0-1)(t_0-2)\cdots (t_0-(p-1))$ is zero because $t_0-t_0$ appears in one of the terms in the product. So $f(t_0)=0-t_0^{p-1}+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ by Fermat's little theorem!

So the polynomial $f(t)$ has $p$ roots modulo $p$. However it's degree is $\leq p-1$. By the observation I made at the beginning, this forces $f$ to be the zero polynomial modulo $p$. This means that every coefficient of $f$ is divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 0):

$deg (f)\leq p-2$ since the $x^{p-1}$ cancel. But using Fermat's little theorem, we see that $f$ has $p-1$ roots. Considering, every non-constant polynomial of degree $n$ over an arbitrary field has, at most, $n$ roots, $f$ can have $p-1$ roots if it's the zero polynomial modulo $p$, therefore every coeffcient is divisible by $p$ as required.